# substr() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given PHP Error on line 588

Tags: php

I have a problem with a certain function with this error and I can't deal with it:
With php5 no problem and working, but with php7 it's not working.

substr() expects parameter 3 to be integer, string given
PHP Error on line 588 in...

And this is the function:

```
public function decode( &$raw, &$offset )
    {
        $end = strpos( $raw, ":", $offset );
        $len = substr( $raw, $offset, $end - $offset );
        $offset += $len + ( $end - $offset );
        ++$end;
        $this->value = substr($raw, $end, $len);
    }
```

Line 588 is: $this->value = substr($raw, $end, $len);

I'm trying to migrate from php5 to php7

Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Three lines earlier the code is loading `$len` as a string.  Can you do a `var_dump($len)` and see what it actually contains?

Comment: `With php5 no problem and working, but with php7 it's not working`...it was not necessarily _working_ in a way that would have actually made any logical sense, it's just that PHP5 didn't warn you about the logical flaw (which is a bad thing - hence why you now get prompted in later PHP versions). Think about it - if the 3rd parameter to the function is supposed to be a number, then your code needs to make sure it supplies a number , and not anything else. Otherwise it might not do what you expect it's going to.

Comment: Since `substr` itself returns a string, and `$len` is assigned the return value from a call to substr, therefore it must be a string. Whether that might happen to be coerceable to an int we don't know that depends on the supplied values of `$raw` and `$offset`, which you neglected to provide us any test cases for. We can't predict precisely what your code will do, or why, if you don't give us relevant input data to work with.

Comment: var_dump($len) contains: string(1) "8" string(0) "" string(10) "announce80" string(9) "nnounce80" string(8) "nounce80" string(7) "ounce80" string(6) "unce80" string(5) "nce80" string(4) "ce80" string(2) "80" string(1) "0" string(0) "" string(4) "http" string(3) "ttp" string(2) "tp" string(1) "p" string(0) "" string(77) "//tracker./announce.php?passkey=323b5784a466800174800fb33ec55def14" string(76) "/tracker./announce.php?passkey=323b5784a466800174800fb33ec55def14" string(75) ....

Comment: Clearly only a very few of those strings are numbers.  What is this code supposed to do?  It's hard to see how this has ever worked, it was probably the case that the earlier PHP version just wasn't showing you the errors. I would suggest going back and fixing the logic

Comment: This is the entire contents of the file:   https://pastebin.com/SeqDkSrr

Comment: You need to explain the logic it's supposed to implement

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an attempt to find a byte string in a Bencoded string (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode), possibly related to a torrent.  From the extra `var_dump` output, it seems to be being called with a variety of string inputs, not all of them valid.

I suggest you change

```
$len = substr( $raw, $offset, $end - $offset );
```

to

```
$len = (int) substr( $raw, $offset, $end - $offset );
```

This will explicitly coerce `$len` to be an integer, and thus avoid the error you are seeing.  However, it does mask the problem that this function is being called with data that isn't valid.

Comment: Not working bro